# clearInterval and jQuery... undefined! + Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to simulate an loading bar, so i decided to use setInterval to update the bar width...but i must clear the interval after page load becouse it causing to much overheat etc. I maked an Fiddle to show you how it works. Thanks in advice , and sorry for bad english! 
http://jsfiddle.net/ItalianD3V/8PPa6/

```
//RUN AN FUNCTION
var updatebar = setInterval(loadbar, Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 30);

//HOW ON THE ERATH TO STOP IT!!?
clearInterval(updatebar);
```

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: @adeneo "HOW ON THE ERATH TO STOP IT!!?" I believe is the question :)

Comment: @DrydenLong - I'd guess by uncommenting that line -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8PPa6/1/

Comment: Yeah xD it's the problem i cant stop it!

Comment: Does JavaScript work the same on Erath, or does the higher gravity affect it?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - The interval and variable references should work fine, but Math operators will be off by 3.333333% on Erath.

Comment: so what i supposed to do?

Comment: If i uncomment "that line" the "loadingbar" doesnt show up :/

Comment: That's because the window loads that fast, what are you expecting ?

Comment: Veeeeryyyy strange...now it work: WHYYYY? Demon-frustation: http://jsfiddle.net/ItalianD3V/8PPa6/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just kill it when it grows enough!

```
if (barwid < 0.91) {
    $("#progress").width($("#progress").width() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 6);
}
else {                                // Grown enough?
    clearInterval(updatebar);         // BOOM! The Erath is safe again!
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8PPa6/3/

I assume you'd like your progress bar to be bound to some real data, to actually reflect the amount of page loaded.

Comment: One problem...it must disappear when the doc is loaded. Thanks for your help, spaceman! :D

Comment: @AgeLonglife You're welcome! :D Yes, that's why I wrote that last sentence. Your progress bar and the amount of page data/elements/images/whatever are not connected. You can attach an onload listener to every big element on the page, and update the progress bar according to it. Then, just remove it. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8PPa6/6/ But again, you need to connect the bar to the load amount.

Comment: How (on the Mars) i can do it? I must prevent to grow to much, and then on load....what? XD Can i just bind the clear function to onload event??

Comment: Window onload fires when the DOM is ready, not when all images, etc. are loaded.

Comment: I'm increasing the loaded counter each time an image loads and I'm updating the progress bar width based on `loaded images` / `total images`. I was thinking you should use something like that (no idea what you're loading on your page, but the idea is the same) instead of a timed bar.

Comment: Actually, the 10 wasn't updated, this one is better: http://jsfiddle.net/8PPa6/12/

Comment: Yeah good idea! I implement it the next relase, for i now i just take the old version: "jaas parruc chieri . com". When done i will update this post! Good Night from Italy.